# Error in SQLiteOpenhelper

Tags: android

I have an error in one class and I don't know why. The error is:

The method openOrCreateDatabase(String, int, null) is undefined for the type Bdoh

The code:

```
public class Bdoh extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
String bdcons = "CREATE TABLE lugares (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    nombre TEXT, descripcion TEXT, latitud DOUBLE, longitud DOUBLE, foto TEXT)";
SQLiteOpenHelper sbd;
SQLiteDatabase db=openOrCreateDatabase("lugares",Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null); 
Cursor cr;
String TBD="lugares"; 

public Bdoh(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) 
{
    super(context, "lugares", null, 1);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(bdcons);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS lugares");

    //Se crea la nueva versión de la tabla
    db.execSQL(bdcons);
}

public void insertar(SQLiteDatabase db) //abre la base de datos e inserta registros
{

        db=sbd.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void estabd(SQLiteDatabase db, double latitude, double longitude)  
{
    String bdcon = "SELECT latitud, longitud from lugares where latitud=lat 
            AND lng=longitud";
    db.execSQL(bdcon);

}

}
```

I think it's a question of object declared wrong. I tried to solve it typing

SQLiteDatabase db=this.openOrCreateDatabase("lugares",Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);

But the error is not deleted.

How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: check the doc http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html. Scroll down to check openOrCreateDatabase(params). Check what should be the params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor initialize your object.

```
SQLiteDatabase db;
```

In the constructor :

```
db=context.openOrCreateDatabase("lugares",Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The database is created automatically when you call `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWritableDatabase`

You can rewrite your constructor so it only takes the `Context` as a paramter, like this:

```
public Bdoh(Context context) {
    super(context, "lugares", null, 1);
}
```

And when you want to write or read from the database you can just create a `Bdoh` (lol) object and ask for a readable or writable database. The first time you call one of those methods the systems creates the database for you and calls the `onCreate` method from `Bdoh`

Answer (score 0):

use like that

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
        private static final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";

        // ---this method will creates database implicitly---
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, dnname.DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
            Log.v(TAG + ".DatabaseHelper:", "DatabaseHelper constructor called");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.v(TAG + ".onCreate:", "Empty Database created");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.v(TAG + ".onUpgrade:", "onUpgrade called");

            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS titles");
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }
```